# Handsontable add comments to custom context menu

Tags: handsontable

On the Comments page, http://handsontable.com/demo/comments.html, it states that to enable comments you can just add 'comments: true' to the options. However, if you have a custom context menu, how do you add the "Add/Edit Comment" and "Delete Comment" to the menu? The below example will not add the two options to the end of the menu.

```
contextMenu: {
  items: {
     "undo": {},
     "redo": {}
  }
},
comments: true
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8sk3xrsu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the add/edit and remove comment keys as part of context menu options, similar to "undo" and "redo" options as specified under "items".

Hence, you above code changes to :

```
contextMenu: {
  items: {
    "undo": {},
    "redo": {},
    "commentsAddEdit":{},
    "commentsRemove":{}
  }
},
comments: true
```

Refer to fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/hphdf0uj/** for live demo.

Hope it will be helpful for you :)

Comment: That's strange. I tried that in my actual project's code and it didn't work, so I didn't bother trying it in a fiddle... I ended up copying and pasting the code used in handsontable's comments.js and then it worked for me in my project: http://jsfiddle.net/ovg9L7xj/1/